# Restrict the maximum quantity to select in a drop down to the value returned from a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, count

In my Ruby on Rails application I currently have the methods:

```
def remaining_seats
  seats.count - bookings.sum(:seats_quantity)
end

def screens_info
  "#{name} (#{remaining_seats}/#{seats.count} remaining)"
end
```

Which return the amount of seats that are available to be booked, for example if there have been two bookings which have booked 6 seats each in a 20 screen cinema it'll say there are 8/20 remaining.

What I want to do is use this so that in this drop down menu where the user selects the amount of seats they require:

```
<%= f.select :seats_quantity, '1'..'10' %>
```

Rather than having the range 1-10 the user can only select a quantity up to the amount of seats remaining. So, from the above example, if there are 8 seats available the user could select up to 8 seats from the drop down menu.

Ideally what I would like is to have a restriction of the maximum amount of seats being selected as 10, then if there are 9 available it would go to 9 or if there are only 3 seats available it would have the maximum of 3.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change `1..10` to `'1'..remaining_seats.to_s`

Comment: That gives this error: `NameError in Bookings#new  undefined local variable or method remaining_seats`

Comment: This worked: `f.select :seats_quantity, '1'..@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats.to_s` thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I could restrict this to 10 if it is over 10?

Comment: define a new method that checks if its 10 or more, somethink like this:
`remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : remaining_seats`

Comment: You can also just do `'1'..(@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats > 10 ? 10 : @booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats).to_s`

Comment: Same, but maybe more "rubyesque" '1'..[@booking.showing.screen.remaining_seats, 10].min.to_s